# Chartjs Graph is not showing in colorbox

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to display a Doughnut Chart in the popup(colorbox) with the dummy values but it is giving error, but if i simply call it in browser(via url) it display the graph.

> IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount.

```js
 var DoughnutChart = [{
        value: 60,
        color: "#fcc79e"
    }, {
        value: 30,
        color: "#beefd2"
    }, {
        value: 50,
        color: "#ffddfb"
    }, {
        value: 20,
        color: "#cdecff"
    }, {
        value: 90,
        color: "#fff5bc"
    }];


    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(DoughnutChart);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Still waiting for someone response.

Answer (score 2):

Chart.js needs the canvas to have a rendered size before it can be rendered. So you need to have your chart initialization inside the `cbox_complete` event hook instead of doing it first and then opening the colorbox

Something like

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function () {
    var DoughnutChart = [{
        ...

        ...
    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(DoughnutChart);
});
```